# Why am I getting spurious TOC entries in Calibre?

Tags: calibre, table-of-contents

I'm converting an RTF document to epub (and mobi) and am trying to extract a table of contents.

All of my chapters start with the word "CHAPTER" in all caps, but are not tagged in any special way.  I'm using the following XPATH expression to find the chapters:

//*[re:test(., "CHAPTER")]

This is working except that my TOC looks like this:

[image: Bad TOC]

As you can see, the table of contents includes the cover page text as several chapters that all point to the first page.

Also I'm getting duplicate entries for each chapter.

I was able to fix this with the manual TOC editor, but I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong with my detection approach.